# Rails route not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure what is going on here. This is working perfectly in development and throws an error in production. Rake routes shows the path the same in each environment as the dashboard_path. Ruby version and rails version are the same in both. I restarted the server, reinitialized unicorn, bundle, db:reset, everything in both environments. I'm pulling my hair out.

Error message

```
I, [2015-06-16T03:31:50.600950 #12311]  INFO -- :   Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.7ms)
I, [2015-06-16T03:31:50.601165 #12311]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms
F, [2015-06-16T03:31:50.603417 #12311] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `dashboard_path' for #<#    <Class:0x000000052151b0>:0x00000004c35448>):
    1: <td>
    2:   <%= link_to page.name, dashboard_path(page) %>
    3: </td>
    4: <td id="page_select_form">
    5:   <% if page.group.nil?%>
  app/views/pages/_page.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_pages__page_html_erb__2539077092639507273_42387000'
  app/views/pages/index.html.erb:19:in `block in _app_views_pages_index_html_erb___1631868800231267778_43030140'
  app/views/pages/index.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_pages_index_html_erb___1631868800231267778_43030140'
```

index.html.erb

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="std-heading">Pages</h3>
    <h4 class="std-create"><%= link_to "Create Page", new_page_path %></h4>
    <div class="column">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
         <% if current_company.pages.empty? %>
           <p>It looks like you don't have any pages yet. Create one <%= link_to 'here!', new_page_path %></p>
         <% else %>
            <tr class="firstrow">
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Assigned Group</b></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
          <% current_company.pages.each do |page| %>
                <tr>
                  <%= render page %>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the partial

```
<td>
  <%= link_to page.name, dashboard_path(page) %>
</td>
<td id="page_select_form">
  <% if page.group.nil?%>
    <p>Unassigned</p>
  <% else %>
    <%= simple_form_for page do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :group_id, collection: @groups, 
            select: page.group, 
            label: false, 
            include_blank: false %>
    <%= f.submit :submit, class: "btn" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to 'Edit Page', page %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to("Delete Page", page_path(page), 
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, :class => 'button-xs') %>
</td>
```

routes.rb

```
get '/pages/:id/dashboard', to: 'pages#dashboard', as: :dashboard
```

Here is the relevant rake routes from production (identical to development)

```
 mercury_update_page POST   /pages/:id/mercury_update(.:format) pages#mercury_update
               pages GET    /pages(.:format)                    pages#index
                     POST   /pages(.:format)                    pages#create
            new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)                pages#new
           edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)           pages#edit
                page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)                pages#show
                     PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)                pages#update
                     PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)                pages#update
                     DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)                pages#destroy
                     PUT    /pages/:id/mercury_update(.:format) pages#mercury_update
              groups GET    /groups(.:format)                   groups#index
                     POST   /groups(.:format)                   groups#create
           new_group GET    /groups/new(.:format)               groups#new
          edit_group GET    /groups/:id/edit(.:format)          groups#edit
               group GET    /groups/:id(.:format)               groups#show
                     PATCH  /groups/:id(.:format)               groups#update
                     PUT    /groups/:id(.:format)               groups#update
                     DELETE /groups/:id(.:format)               groups#destroy
  groups_select_page POST   /groups/select_page(.:format)       groups#select_page
                     GET    /q/:path(.:format)                  q_rcodes#new
                     GET    /t/:path(.:format)                  tags#processurl
                     GET    /pages/view/:path(.:format)         pages#view
           dashboard GET    /pages/:id/dashboard(.:format)      pages#dashboard
                home GET    /home(.:format)                     home#index
```

Please help!

Comment: If you ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake routes` in production, does the route show up?

Comment: try instead dashboard_path(page), dashboard_url(page)

Comment: Please post your `index.html.erb`

Comment: run your application in production mode

Comment: The route shows up in both production and development. index.html.erb has been posted. dashboard_url(page) doesn't work either.

Comment: @socialconquest might sound silly but did you push updated routes file on server?

Comment: Not silly, but yes. I have run rake routes server side as well and the route shows up on the remote.

Comment: @socialconquest if it works in development and not in production then inspect your page object in both cases and try to find the missing link

Comment: Page object is the same in both, just checked. The route function dashboard_path works in development and doesn't in production.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line in your `index.html.erb`

```
<%= render page %>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: "page", locals: { page: page } %>
```

***Note:*** Be careful in naming the files in Rails. In your case your model name and view page name(`_page.html.erb`) has the same name(**page**) which is enough to confuse the Rails.

***Update***

Try passing a different instance.May be the **instance(page)** is conflicting with **model(page)**

In your `index.html.erb`, make these changes

```
<% current_company.pages.each do |company_page| %>
   <tr>
     <%= render partial: "page", locals: { company_page: company_page } %>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

And in your `_page.html.erb`

Change this line

```
<%= link_to page.name, dashboard_path(page) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to company_page.name, dashboard_path(company_page) %>
```

Comment: Solid advice but didn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it out but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: @socialconquest Are you sure,still the same error `undefined method dashboard_path`?

Comment: Yep, just double checked it. undefined method 'dashboard_path'.